# Attempt to spin a callback queue from two spinners, one of them being single-threaded

Tags: ros, ros-controllers, ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I followed [this guide](https://slaterobots.com/blog/5abd8a1ed4442a651de5cb5b/how-to-implement-ros_control-on-a-custom-robot) to implement a controller for my [rotary stage](https://www.newport.com/p/URS100BCC). Everything works just fine, but when I launch my controller, I get the following error (which does not impair the functionality of my controller btw.):

```
[ERROR] [1548319318.740806716]: SpinnerMonitor: single-threaded spinner after multi-threaded one(s).Attempt to spin a callback queue from two spinners, one of them being single-threaded. In the future this will throw an exception! Only allowed for backwards compatibility.
```

The error is probably caused, when executing my controller executable of my hardware interface. The code, where I create my hardware interface looks like this:

```
#include "urs100_hardware_interface/urs100_hardware_interface.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "urs100_hardware_interface");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
spinner.start();
urs100_hardware_interface::Urs100HardwareInterface Urs100Stage(nh);
ros::spin();
return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get rid of that error? I already tried to get rid of the ros::spin() and put the spinner.start() right before the return.
Would really like to know how to implement this spinning functionality properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313629/attempt-to-spin-a-callback-queue-from-two-spinners,-one-of-them-being-single-threaded/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  [..]
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  [..]
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

That `ros::spin()` should not be used here, as `AsyncSpinner` is already processing your queues (that's what the error message also tells you).

If you don't have some other blocking action in your control flow of the node, you can use `ros::waitForShutdown()`.

See the comments on `ros::AsyncSpinner` on the ROS wiki: [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning: Multi-threaded Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-01-24**:
Thanks for your answer. The following code worked for me:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "urs100_hardware_interface");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(2);
urs100_hardware_i
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
Your last comment confuses me: that is not a typical flow of control I would expect with a hw interface.

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-01-24**:
When I writing the hardware interface, I implemented a blocking method and a non blocking method to move the stage. I know that blocking functions are not supposed to be in the hw interface since it harms the sampling time of the controller, but this just worked fine for me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
As long as you're aware that you're breaking the (implicit) contract between you and whatever is loading and spinning your hw interface implementation.

**Comment by [Jose_M](https://answers.ros.org/users/40130/jose_m/) on 2019-02-20**:
Excuse me sir, did you manage to make it works? I'm trying the same process but got this message error:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Also i changed the ros::spin() for ros::waitForShutdown(), so i'll appreciate if you could help me

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-02-21**:
Hi, this is, what worked for me:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "urs100_hardware_interface");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(2);
urs100_hardware_interface::Urs100HardwareInterface Urs100Stage(nh);
spinner.start();
ros::waitForShutdown();
```

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-02-21**:
You might have to adjust the thread count depending on your needs.